# Don't understand head of for loop

Tags: c++, list, for-loop

I found this code snippet (a bit modified) on "cplusplus.com" reference for `std::vector::emplace` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/).
I have already often worked with `lists` and I know the `auto` keyword.
But I don't understand the head of the for loop.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
  std::list<int> list;

  list.emplace_back(100);
  list.emplace_back(200);

  std::cout << "list contains: ";
  for (auto& x: list)
    std::cout << "(" << x << ") ";

  return 0;
}
```

Output: `list contains: (100) (200)`

Comment: [It's a for-each loop.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) Also called a range-based for loop.

Comment: thank you. Now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointed out in the comment, it's a `for-each loop`. The loop literally means `for each x in list, print x`.

You are probably confused by the `auto& x`. It's accessing by reference (an alias to an existing variable name). You can read more about [C++ references](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm).